# Shutdown Cassandra server and then restart it in windows 7

Tags: cassandra, port, shutdown

I installed single node cluster in my local dev box which is running Windows 7 and it was working fine. Due to some reason, I need to restart my desktop and then after that whenever I am doing like this on the command prompt, it always gives me the below exception-

```
S:\Apache Cassandra\apache-cassandra-1.2.3\bin>cassandra -f
Starting Cassandra Server
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Meaning port being used somewhere. I have made some changes in `cassandra.yaml` file so I need to shutdown the `Cassandra server` and then restart it again.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: whenever you are trying to connect via cli. whats the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running -f starts the server as a service, you can stop it through the `task manager`.

It sounds like your Cassandra server starts on it's own as a service in the background when your machine boots. You can [configure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/758.disable-and-enable-windows-7-startup-programs.aspx) windows startup services. To run cassandra in the foreground on windows simply use:

```
> cassandra.bat
```

Answer (score 7):

in windows7, with apache cassandra, a pid.txt file gets created at the root folder of cassandra. Give following instruction to stop the server:

*d:/cassandra/bin> stop-server -p ../pid.txt -f*

Answer (score 3):

If your are using Cassandra bundled with DataStax Community Edition and running as a service on startup of your machine then you can execute following commands to start and stop Cassandra server.

Start command prompt with admin rights

run following commands

```
      net start DataStax_Cassandra_Community_Server

      net stop DataStax_Cassandra_Community_Server
```